# why it didn't catch the rejected promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was wondering why the `try-catch` block couldn't catch the promise rejected from `foo`.

Frustrated, need help. Thanks in advance.

```js
function addTask(task) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    task.resolver()
  }, 1000)
}

function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const task = {
      resolver: function() {
        reject('task failed')
      }
    }
    addTask(task)
  })
}

function test() {
  try {
    foo()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

// Uncaught (in promise) task failed
test()
```

Comment: afaik try/catch only works with promises when using async/await syntax

Comment: barring special syntax 1) foo returns immediately; 2) try block only has foo call, so it also completes immediately. By the time promise is rejected, it should be intuitive that you're not in bounds of try/catch block anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same reason that if you had:

```
const result = foo();
```

Then you would have a promise stored in `result` and not the settled value of the promise.

The asynchronous code is started, then the calling function continues.

Sometime *later* the promise is rejected, but by then it is too late for the code in `test()` to catch it.

---

If you had `await`ed `foo()`, which would require that `test()` be `async`, then it would be caught.

Otherwise you could need to use `foo().catch(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are asynchronous but you are not *awaiting*. It means code continues. So you have to `await` or you have to use `then().catch()`. Something like this:

```js
function addTask(task) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    task.resolver()
  }, 1000)
}

function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const task = {
      resolver: function() {
        reject('task failed')
      }
    }
    addTask(task)
  })
}

function test() {
  foo().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
}

// Uncaught (in promise) task failed
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your example:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000))
}

function test() {
  try {
    foo()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error");
    return;
  }
  console.log("OK!");
}

test()
```

will print "OK!" indeed have Node.js raise an UnhandledPromiseRejection, as that `foo()` invocation is just "throwing away" the promise result value. The `catch()` would only catch synchronous exceptions, not promise rejections.

Turning the function into `async function test()` and `await`ing on `foo()` will correctly output `Error` and no unhandled rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Add await before `foo()` call and async before test function declaration

like below

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    task.resolver()
  }, 1000)
}

function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const task = {
      resolver: function() {
        reject('task failed')
      }
    }
    addTask(task)
  })
}

async function test() {
  try {
   await foo()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

// Uncaught (in promise) task failed
test()`
```